# Derivative of eigenvalues with respect to parameter

Tags: differentiation, eigenvalue, matrix-elements

By trying to find precise ways to calculate the derivative of numerical Hermitian matrices, I've recently stumbled upon [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2588473/derivatives-of-eigenvalues) in Math Stack Exchange. From the first answer on that post we get an expression for the derivative of the eigenvalues with respect to the matrix entries. From that we get that for a Hermitian matrix $\mathbf{H}$ parametrized by a real quantity $\varphi$, its eigenvalues $E_p(\varphi)$ and the unitary matrix that diagonalizes it $\mathbf{U}$, the following identity holds:
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial E_p}{\partial\varphi}
&= \sum_{ij} \frac{\partial E_p}{\partial \mathbf{H}_{ij}} \frac{\partial \mathbf{H}_{ij}}{\partial \varphi} \\
&= \left[ \mathbf{U}\frac{\partial \mathbf{H}}{\partial \varphi}\mathbf{U}^{\dagger} \right]_{pp}.
\end{align}

I was not able to find this information anywhere else and the references presented to the original expression in that post have a bit more complicated math that I find hard to follow.

My main question regarding it is:

**Does this expression generalize to higher order derivatives? That is, does the following expression hold?**

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial^n E_p}{\partial\varphi^n}
&\stackrel{?}{=} \left[ \mathbf{U}\frac{\partial^n \mathbf{H}}{\partial \varphi^n}\mathbf{U}^{\dagger} \right]_{pp}
\end{align}

Comment: I didn’t work it out for your case but Matrix Cookbook has some relevant formulae. https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf

Comment: @Brick Thanks, that's a nice resource I didn't know about. If I find an answer to my question I'll be sure to send it to the authors of that document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is standard Rayleigh-Schroedinger perturbation  theory, but described a bit differently from how it is usually done in quantum mechanucs books.  Here (assuming a non-degenerate spectrum)  is the quickes route to the usual treatment:

Suppose that we have an eigenvector $|n\rangle$ with eigenvalue $E_n$
$$
H|n\rangle= E_n |n\rangle.
$$
Then differentiate with resoect to the parameter to get
$$
dH |n\rangle+ Hd|n\rangle= dE_n |n\rangle +E_n d|n\rangle
$$
Find matrix elements by applying   $\langle m|$ to this get
$$
\langle m|dH |n\rangle+ \langle m| Hd|n\rangle= dE_n \langle m|n\rangle +E_n \langle m|d|n\rangle.
$$
Firtly take $m=n$ so
$$
\langle n|dH |n\rangle+ \langle n| Hd|n\rangle= dE_n \langle n|n\rangle +E_n \langle n|d|n\rangle.
$$
or
$$
\langle n|dH |n\rangle+ E_n\langle n| d|n\rangle= dE_n \langle n|n\rangle +E_n \langle n|d|n\rangle,
$$
so
$$
\langle n|dH |n\rangle=  dE_n \langle n|n\rangle. 
$$
This is your (and Feynman- Helmann's) equation.
Now let $m\ne n$ and assume that $d|n\rangle$ is orthogonal to $|n\rangle$ (This does not preserve normaliztaion but this will not matter)

Now we get
$$
\langle m|dH |n\rangle+ E_m \langle m| d|n\rangle=  +E_n \langle m|d|n\rangle,
$$
so
$$
\langle m| d|n\rangle = \frac{\langle m|dH |n\rangle}{E_n-E_m}.
$$
Now you know how the derivative $$
dE_n\equiv \frac{dE_n}{d\lambda}$$
of the eigenvalue and $$
d|n\rangle\equiv \frac{d}{d\lambda}|.n\rangle
$$ of the eigenevctor.  You can use these formulae to compute the second derivative of $E_n$ and so on. the answers rapidly get much [more complicated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perturbation_theory_(quantum_mechanics)) (see the section in the cited Wikipedia article called "Second-order and higher-order corrections").

Comment: Interesting. I hadn't thought of connecting it to perturbation theory because it's not usually written with derivatives. The "Second order and higher-order corrections" section you mentioned, for example, uses no derivatives. Only under the [Hellmann–Feynman theorems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perturbation_theory_(quantum_mechanics)#Hellmann%E2%80%93Feynman_theorems) I found expressions using derivatives. Is my first equation equivalent to the first of these theorems?

Comment: @Lucas Baldo. Yes your formula is just Feynman Helmann. The series in Wiki is is just their rather tedious way of writing the  Taylor expansion withiout using  derivatives. Keep applying my formulae and you will get their expressions, although they might look different because of some cancellations in the sums over intermediate states,

Comment: Thanks! Also, as far as I know, in usual perturbation theory one thinks of a parameter $\lambda$ that is taken to be small and a perturbing Hamiltonian $V$, such that $H = H_0 + \lambda V$. These elements seem to be missing in the Hellmann-Feynman formulation, so I don't see the exact connection between the two frameworks. In other words, I don't see what are we perturbing in the Hellmann-Feynman description and how we are perturbing it.

Comment: In this context Feyman-Helmann sets $dH/d\lambda= V$ and  all higher derivatives of $H$ are zero.

Comment: So it doesn't work if H depends on $\lambda$ non-linearly?

Comment: Why do you think that?  Using $\lambda V$ is just a special simple case of the general F-H theorem.

Comment: Hm, I see. I hadn't understood that it $dH/d\lambda = V$ was just a special case. Now it makes sense. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

During the last days I have found out that my initial guess was incomplete and I'm posting here to share what I have found.

The terms with derivatives of $\mathbf{U}$ can contribute non-trivially to the expression for derivatives of order higher than one. I have calculated an expression for the second-order case. The derivation is too long for a Stack Exchange answer, I believe, but it can be found in detail [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZIdSAfQwrS1y6dNjPC0bNKaZnyM6pefK/view?usp=sharing).

The final result I've found is
\begin{align}
    \frac{\partial^2 \epsilon_p}{\partial \varphi^2}
    &= \left( \mathbf{U} \frac{\partial^2 \mathbf{H}}{\partial \varphi^2} \mathbf{U}^{\dagger} \right)_{pp} + 2 \left( \mathbf{U} \frac{\partial \mathbf{H}}{\partial \varphi} \mathbf{U}^{\dagger} \mathbf{A} \right)_{pp},
\end{align}
where $\mathbf{A}$ is defined by
\begin{align}
    \mathbf{A}_{ab}
    &= 
\begin{cases}
0, \quad a=b \\
(\epsilon_b - \epsilon_a)^{-1} \left( \mathbf{U} \frac{\partial \mathbf{H}}{\partial \varphi} \mathbf{U}^{\dagger} \right)_{ab}, \quad a \neq b.
\end{cases}
\end{align}

I'm still looking for possible errors in the derivation and I have no idea if this method will extend for higher order derivatives. Feedback on both is welcome.